# Check String null or empty and replace with another string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In here i want to, If AvailCode comes as a `null` or `empty` string then i need to show it "Temporary Unavailable".But my coding doen't show that one. (Consider only Avail Code).

```
var _staff = trv.GetBookDetails("4500").Select(b => new
{
    value = b.bookno,
    text =  b.bookname + " " + "/"+" " + b.AvailCode ?? "TemporaryUnavailable",  
});
```

Comment: `text = String.Format("{0} / {1}", b.bookname, String.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AvailCode) ? "TemporaryUnavailable" : b.AvailCode);`

Comment: Above comment code also work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [??](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) operator only handles the `NULL` case, not the empty case

replace

```
b.AvailCode ?? "TemporaryUnavailable"
```

with

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AvailCode)? "TemporaryUnavailable" : b.AvailCode
```

so the correct line would be

```
text = b.bookname + " / " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AvailCode) ? "TemporaryUnavailable" : b.AvailCode),
```

Comment: It shows me the error "Cannot implycitly convert type bool to string"

Answer (score 2):

[`??`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator which called null-coalescing operator returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

This **won't** check for empty;

Use [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead.

```
string.IsNullOrWhitespace(b.AvailCode) ? "TemporaryUnavailable" : b.AvailCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Operator `??` has very low precedence, it's evaluated after the `+` operators on the left side. Therefore you can never really get `null` on the left side. You need to wrap into parenthesis:

```
  text =  b.bookname + " " + "/"+" " + (b.AvailCode ?? "TemporaryUnavailable"),
```

or, in case you want to handle also empty:

```
  text =  b.bookname + " " + "/"+" " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.AvailCode) ? "TemporaryUnavailable" : b.AvailCode),
```